# Is it possible to put an android code in intel xdk ? because i'm planning add a module that will interact the power button

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, intel-xdk

Is it possible to put an andriod code in intel xdk? because i'm planning add a module that will interact the power button.

module that i want to make/add is when the power  button pressed twice or thrice, the application will start while locked.

Answer (score 0):

yup.  research codova/phonegap plugins and create one yourself.

Then you can incorperate that plugin you created with intel-xdk.  Here's a nice tutorial by the xdk team:  [Adding Plugins to Your Intel® XDK Cordova* App](https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/adding-third-party-plugins-to-your-xdk-cordova-app).